# How to join 2 tables in codeigniter PHP?

Tags: codeigniter

I have 2 tables guest_info and guest_profile.two columns are there g_uid and company_id.Based on company_id(I have companyID), i have to take all g_uid.
In guest_info table,

g_uid | companyID

1        5

2        5

3        6

In guest_profile table,display all values from this table(only need to display first two datas)

g_uid | fname

1         xyz

2         fds

3         fsdf

Comment: show your code what you had try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to folder "Models" That´s where you´ll do all your CRUD operations to the database.
For example, you can create a model file called "guest_profile_model.php"

Now you open that file and paste the code bellow:

```
       <?php

    class guest_profile_model extends CI_Model {

public function select($company_id) {

$this->db->query("select * from `guest_info` INNER JOIN `guest_profile` ON guest_info.g_uid = guest_profile.g_uid WHERE guest_info.company_id = ".$company_id." LIMIT 2");
 $result = $this->db->query($query); 

 return $result->result_object();
}
    }
```

That´s it, now from within your controller you just need to load and call it.
Example:

```
  $this-> load-> model('guest_profile_model ');
    $company_id = 1;
    $queryResult = $this -> guest_profile_model ->select(company_id);

    print_r($queryResult);
```

Notice that the query return is going to be an object, that is because of the "result_object" in the model, you can change that to be an array if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this sql query to join 2 table in codeigniter
$company_id = 5;
$this->db->query("select * from `guest_info` INNER JOIN `guest_profile` ON guest_info.g_uid = guest_profile.g_uid WHERE guest_info.company_id = ".$company_id." LIMIT 2");
```

Comment: where i need to give company id?

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Table1 AS a');
$this->db->join('Table2 AS b', 'a.id = c.id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('Table3 AS c', 'a.name = c.name', 'LEFT');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

hopefully you get my example.
More info : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=joins#selecting-data